# why bootstrap uses unit-less line-height for buttons whereas pixel based line-height for margin and padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's `variables.less` file contains the following varibles regarding line-height:

```
//** Unit-less `line-height` for use in components like buttons.
@line-height-base:        1.428571429; // 20/14
//** Computed "line-height" (`font-size` * `line-height`) for use with `margin`, `padding`, etc.
@line-height-computed:    floor((@font-size-base * @line-height-base)); // ~20px
```

As comments show, unit-less line-height is indeed used for buttons:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0; // For input.btn
  ...
  .button-size(...; @line-height-base; ...);  
}
```

Where is pixel based line-height is used for margins, for example here:

```
.alert {
  padding: @alert-padding;
  margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;
  ...
}
```

I'm wondering why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unitless margin and padding is not legal css, while unitless line-height is in relation to the font-size.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: thanks, so what you're thinking that if unitless margin and padding was possible, than it would be set with `@line-height-base` variable?

Comment: Yeah I think so, what they are doing is setting a margin bottom to be equal to a line of text, probably to get a nice typographic vertical rhytm http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/vertical_rhythm/